# Why do arima predictions change depending on start/end points?

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am trying to generate some ARIMA predictions based on a model I fit to some training data.  My total data set consists of monthly data from January 2017 - April 2020.  I define my train set as the months of January 2017 - January 2020, and my test set as the months of Feb 2020 - Apr 2020. I do not have any data beyond this.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA 

arima_fit_test = ARIMA(train, order=(3,0,5)).fit()
```

I noticed that despite using the exact same model above, if I generate predictions for a different set period of time, i.e. 3 months vs 5 months, my predictions are slightly different (specifically, for the month of April 2020):

```
# predictions for test set only:
arima_predictions1 = arima_fit_test.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train)+len(test)-1)
# predictions for test set + 2 additional time steps
arima_predictions2 = arima_fit_test.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train)+len(test)-1+2)
```

Output:

```
arima_predictions1

2020-02-01    8538738.52975
2020-03-01    8544609.80394
2020-04-01    7500561.77990

arima_predictions2

2020-02-01    8538738.52975
2020-03-01    8544609.80394
2020-04-01    7885846.88085
2020-05-01    8376855.52546
2020-06-01    8282621.83543
```

Why are the predictions different for `2020-04-01`? I'm using the exact same model `arima_fit_test` for `arima_predictions1` and `arima_predictions2`, so shouldn't these two sets of predictions match for the first 3 months?  I also noticed that if I use the `.forecast()` method, I get the exact same sort of behavior.

EDIT:
I noticed that this behavior only tends to happen with the last month of the shorter time span.  For example, if `arima_predictions1` above included only `2020-02-01` and `2020-03-01` predictions while `arima_predictions2` included only `2020-02-01`, `2020-03-01`, `2020-04-01`, the predictions for `2020-03-01` would be the only prediction different between the two.

Comment: what happens if you change the `p`, `d`, `q` of ARIMA?

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to be an issue when I select `(3,0,2)`  as my parameters... is there something wrong with choosing `(3,0,5)`?